# Align dates on x axis on multiple Highcharts diagrams

Tags: highcharts

I have three diagrams as the picture below. As you can see the dates align on the last two but on the top line chart the dates does not align with the other two. Can i control this in any way?

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
<div id="statisticsBGDiagramLastMonth" style="width:950px; height:250px;"></div>
<div id="statisticsInsulinDiagramLastMonth" style="width:950px; height:200px;">/div>
<div id="statisticsCarbsDiagramLastMonth" style="width:950px; height:200px;">/div>

$(function () {

            var usersPerClinicDiagram = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'statisticsBGDiagramLastMonth',
                    backgroundColor:'#F8F8FA' 
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Blodsocker'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'

                },

                yAxis: {
                    tickInterval: 10,
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {enabled: true, shared: false,
                    formatter: function() {
                        var text = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d ' + '%H:%M',
                                              new Date(this.x)) + ' ' + this.series.name +
                                   '<br>' + this.y + ' mmol/l';                        
                        return text;
                    }
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'BG',
                    data: @Model.LastMonthPatientBGValuesGraphData,
                    //zIndex: 1,
                    type: 'line',
                    shadow: false,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        fillColor: 'white',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                }]

            });

        });


        $(function () {
            var usersPerClinicDiagram = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'statisticsInsulinDiagramLastMonth',
                    backgroundColor:'#F8F8FA'
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false                   
                },

                title: {text: 'Insulin'},

                tooltip: {enabled: true, shared: false,
                    formatter: function() {
                        var text = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d ',
                                              new Date(this.x)) + ': ' + this.series.name +
                                   '<br>' + this.y + 'E';                        
                        return text;
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {                   
                    type: "datetime"                  
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    tickInterval: 20,
                    stackLabels: {                        
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function(){
                            var val = this.total;
                            if (val > 0) {
                                return val;
                            }
                            return '';
                        },
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '9px',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',                            
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        },                       
                    }               

                },                   

                plotOptions: {                    
                    //line: {dataLabels: {enabled: true, style: {fontSize: '8px'}, style: {textShadow: false}, allowDecimals: true,  formatter: function() {return this.y + 'e'}}},
                    column: {stacking: 'normal', shadow: false, dataLabels: {
                        formatter:function() {
                            if(this.y != 0) {
                                return this.y;
                            }
                        },
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black',
                            fontSize: '8px'
                        }
                    }},
                    //series: {minPointLength: 0}
                },

                credits: { enabled: false },                
                series: [{pointWidth: 25, type: 'column', color: '#009ddf',  name: 'Insulin Basal', allowDecimals:true, data: @Html.Raw(@Model.LastMonthPatientSortedBasalGraphData) }, {pointWidth: 25, type: 'column', color: '#A7CBED',  name: 'Insulin Bolus', allowDecimals:true, data: @Html.Raw(@Model.LastMonthPatientSortedBolusGraphData)}]
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            var usersPerClinicDiagram = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'statisticsCarbsDiagramLastMonth',
                    backgroundColor:'#F8F8FA'
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false                    
                },
                title: {text: 'Kolhydrater'},

                tooltip: {enabled: true, shared: false,
                    formatter: function() {                       
                        var text = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d ',
                                              this.x) + ': ' + this.series.name +
                                   '<br>' + this.y + ' gram';                        
                        return text;
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {text: 'Datum',align: 'high'},
                    type: "datetime",
                    allowDecimals: true,
                },
                yAxis: {                    
                    tickInterval: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function(){
                            var val = this.total;
                            if (val > 0) {
                                return val;
                            }
                            return '';
                        },
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '9px',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },  

                plotOptions: {                   
                    column: {stacking: 'normal', shadow: false},
                    //series: {minPointLength: 0}
                },

                credits: { enabled: false },                
                series: [{ pointWidth: 15, type: 'column', color: '#666666',  name: 'Carbs', allowDecimals:true, data: @Html.Raw(@Model.LastMonthFoodDataGraphData) }]
            });
        });
```

Comment: Could you make live example of your issue? Like jsFiddle?

Comment: Generally speaking, the spacing for a column series and a line series will be different. You can usually work around this by setting the `minPadding` and `maxPadding` for your `xAxis` on the line series through trial and error until it aligns properly, or, you could possibly ad a dummy column series to the line chart that would force the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue and solved it by setting

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, all charts have to have the same left margin (yAxis labels takes more place when the numbers are bigger - disable marginLeft and see the third chart). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0k9kqc51/.